# BasicPropertyAccessor:167 - IllegalArgumentException in class in Struts

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jsp, struts2

I'm working on online exam project using **struts spring and hibernate**. While submitting the values from registration.jsp, i'm trying to insert those details in two different tables by using one table's primary key as foreign key in another table. But i could able to save only values in one table( says primary key table). But i could not able to save details in another table. **In console log**, i could see the follwing exception,

```
2013-09-17 18:16:39 INFO  RegistrationAction:188 - Entering Into SaveUserDetails()
2013-09-17 18:16:39 INFO  class:25 - Entering Into saveUserRegistration()
2013-09-17 18:16:39 INFO  class:13 - Entering Into UserRegistrationDAO
Hibernate: insert into user_details (first_name, last_name, email, password, gender, dob, phone, experience) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
2013-09-17 18:16:39 INFO  RegistrationAction:214 - Entering Into setUserAddress()
2013-09-17 18:16:39 INFO  class:25 - Entering Into saveUserRegistration()
2013-09-17 18:16:39 INFO  class:13 - Entering Into UserRegistrationDAO
2013-09-17 18:16:39 ERROR BasicPropertyAccessor:167 - IllegalArgumentException in class: onlineexam.beans.UserDetails, getter method of property: user_id
Sep 17, 2013 6:16:39 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
```

**RegistrationAction.java**

```
public String SaveUserDetails() {
            String forward = "success";

            try {
                logger.info("Entering Into SaveUserDetails()");//Log Information

                UserDetails s = new UserDetails();
                s.setFirst_name(getFirst_Name());
                s.setLast_name(getLast_Name());
                s.setEmail(getEmailid());
                s.setPassword(getPassWord());
                s.setGender(getGender());
                s.setDob(getDateofbirth());
                s.setPhone(getPhoneNo());
                s.setExperience(getUser_experience());
                userRegistrationService.saveUserRegistration(s);
                Set<UserAddress> address = new HashSet<UserAddress>(0);
                setUserAddress(address);


                logger.info("SuccessFull:Exiting from SaveUserDetails()");//Log Information
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                forward = "error";
            }

            return forward;

        }

        public void setUserAddress(Set<UserAddress> address) throws Exception {
            logger.info("Entering Into setUserAddress()");
               UserAddress ad = new UserAddress();
               ad.setAddr_line1(getAddr_line1());
               ad.setAddr_line2(getAddr_line2());
               ad.setAddr_line3(getAddr_line3());
               ad.setCity(getCity());
               ad.setZipcode(getZipcode());
               ad.setState(getState());
               ad.setCountry(getCountry());
               address.add(ad);
             userRegistrationService.saveUserRegistration(ad);
               logger.info("SuccessFull:Exiting from setUserAddress()");//Log Information
        }
    }
```

**UserRegistrationDAO.java**

```
public class UserRegistrationDao extends HibernateDaoSupport {
    private static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("UserRegistrationDao.class");
    public UserRegistrationDao() {}

    public UserDetails saveUserRegistration(UserDetails s) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Entering Into UserRegistrationDAO");
        return (UserDetails)getHibernateTemplate().merge(s);
    }   

}
```

**UserRegistrationService.java**

```
public class UserRegistrationService {

    private UserRegistrationDao userRegistrationDao;
    private static Logger logger=Logger.getLogger("UserRegistrationService.class");

    public void init() throws Exception {}

    public UserRegistrationDao getUserRegistrationDao() {
        logger.info("Entering into getUserRegistrationDao()");//Log information
        return userRegistrationDao;
    }

    public void setUserRegistrationDao(UserRegistrationDao userRegistrationDao) {
        this.userRegistrationDao = userRegistrationDao;
        logger.info("Entering Into setUserRegistrationDao()");//Log Information
    }

    public UserDetails saveUserRegistration (UserDetails user) throws Exception {
        logger.info("Entering Into saveUserRegistration()");//Log Information
        return userRegistrationDao.saveUserRegistration(user);
    }

}
```

**UserDetails.java**

public class UserDetails {

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
@OneToMany (mappedBy="user_details")

private int user_id; //primary key
private String first_name;
private String last_name;
private String email;
private String password;
private String gender;
private int dob;
private int phone;
private float experience;
//getters and setters created
```

**UserAddress.java**

```
 public class UserAddress extends UserDetails {
        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
        private int address_id; //primary key
        @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=UserDetails.class)
        @JoinColumn(name="user_id")
        private int user_id; 
        private String addr_line1;
        private String addr_line2;
        private String addr_line3;
        private String city;
        private int zipcode;
        private String state;
        private String country;

    //getters and setters created
```

Comment: I don't understand your `setUserAddress(Set<UserAddress> address)` method. It takes a set and adds an `UserAddress` to it but then just saves the `UserAddress`. I think what you are probably missing is either setting `UserDetails` on the `UserAddress` or adding the `Set<UserAddress>` to the `UserDetails`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What are you doing in `UserAddress` doesn't constitute a many to one association from `UserAddress` to `UserDetails`. Your are only adding the `user_id` to `UserDetails` class.
What you have to do instead:

```
@ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.EAGER, targetEntity=UserDetails.class)
@JoinColumn(name="user_id")
UserDetails userDetails;

public UserDetails getUserDetails() {
    return userDetails;
}

public void setUserDetails() {
    this.userDetails = userDetails;
}
```

I don't understand why `UserAddress` extends `UserDetails`? I recommend you to read more about [hibernate associations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#tutorial-associations).